# Ensuring a bash variable includes a line break at the end

Tags: bash

I want to ensure that a variable includes a line break at the end.  What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case $var in
  (*$'\n') echo ends in a newline;;
  (*) echo does not end in a newline;;
esac
```

Note that it's very uncommon for variable values to end in newlines.

Generally, we strip those, and they are added back upon printing.

For instance:

```
echo "$var"
```

prints the contents of `$var` (assuming it doesn't start with `-` and doesn't contain backslashes) followed by a newline. Or we do explicitly:

```
printf '%s\n' "$var"
```

In:

```
basename /path/to/file
```

`basename` outputs `file<newline>`. That newline is not part of the basename of the file, it's only there to make sure the output is a line.

In:

```
var=$(basename -- "$file")
```

Command substitution strips that newline. Actually, it strips **all** trailing newline characters which could be seen as a bug as it also removes the ones that would be part of the basename of the file.

Comment: Knowing that `echo "something"` appends a new line, why does `[[ $(echo  "a") = $(echo -n "a") ]] && echo yes` return true? I see that the new line is ignored when comparing strings in shells.

Comment: Never mind, I think you have mentioned that: `Command substitution strips that newline.`. I misunderstood that line but I think it actually solves my doubt, +1 :-).